# Is it possible to show video face detection in the capture stream?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediacapture

I am using the MediaCapture API for a video recording app.

Part of it is face detection using rectangles, but I would like that to appear in the capture stream, not just the preview stream.

Even though I indicate VideoRecord as the MediaStreamType when adding the effect, the rectangles do not appear in the end-result video, which is my goal.

```
var definition = new FaceDetectionEffectDefinition
 {
    SynchronousDetectionEnabled = false,
    DetectionMode = FaceDetectionMode.HighPerformance
};

try
{
    faceDetectionEffect = (FaceDetectionEffect)await mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(definition, MediaStreamType.VideoRecord);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // Error message
    return;
}
faceDetectionEffect.FaceDetected += FaceDetectionEffect_FaceDetected;
faceDetectionEffect.DesiredDetectionInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
faceDetectionEffect.Enabled = true;
```

Any advice on how to cause face detection and tracking to appear in the capture stream, or the end-result video, as well?

Thanks!

==================================

Basically, I would like face detection and tracking to appear in the CaptureElement so that identity hiding (obscuring the user's face with an image that tracks their face) can be accomplished in the final video.

My code borrows from the Windows universal samples: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

There is a CaptureElement where the video stream from the camera is rendered. To draw the rectangles of the detected faces, a Canvas is used.

```
<CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl"                            
                            Opacity="0.8"
                            Stretch="Fill"
                            IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" />

<Canvas>
    <Canvas Name="FacesCanvas"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                </Canvas>
```

This is how the FaceDetectionEffectDefinition is added to the MediaCapture object, and the FaceDetectionEffect is added...

```
private async Task CreateFaceDetectionEffectAsync()
{
    var definition = new FaceDetectionEffectDefinition
    {
            SynchronousDetectionEnabled = false,
            DetectionMode = FaceDetectionMode.HighPerformance
    };
    try
    {
            faceDetectionEffect = (FaceDetectionEffect)await mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(definition,       MediaStreamType.VideoRecord);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
            //exception.Message.ToString()
            return;
    }
    faceDetectionEffect.FaceDetected += FaceDetectionEffect_FaceDetected;
    faceDetectionEffect.DesiredDetectionInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
    faceDetectionEffect.Enabled = true;
}
```

What goes on inside the FaceDetectionEffect event...

```
private async void FaceDetectionEffect_FaceDetected(FaceDetectionEffect sender, FaceDetectedEventArgs args)
{
    await MainPage.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => HighlightDetectedFaces(args.ResultFrame.DetectedFaces));
}

private void HighlightDetectedFaces(IReadOnlyList<DetectedFace> faces)
{
    facesCanvas.Children.Clear();
    if (softwareBitmapSource == null)
        return;

                for (int i = 0; i < faces.Count; i++)
                {
                    Rectangle faceBoundingBox = ConvertPreviewToUiRectangle(faces[i].FaceBox);                
                    faceBoundingBox.Fill = new ImageBrush
                    {
                            ImageSource = softwareBitmapSource
                    };                
                    facesCanvas.Children.Add(faceBoundingBox);
                }               
}
```

The MediaCapture object get initialized, and is set as the source of the CaptureElement in the beginning...

(Some code, such as specifying the media stream type for VideoPreview and VideoRecord, if not identical, has been omitted.)

```
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = preferredCamera.Id, AudioDeviceId = preferredMicrophone.Id };

await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

PreviewControl.Source = mediaCapture;
```

Hopefully, there is an easier technique, without having to resort to using MediaComposition and overlays.

Comment: Could you please show me more detailed code about the case?

Comment: Thanks for the response, YanGu! I've included some extra code under the original question, however, it may not be necessary.

Comment: My thought is to process every video frame to add the rectangle effect, but it’s hard. Another easier way is to record the video with the rectangle effect by using Windows.Media.AppRecording namespace in your app, but it will reduce video clarity. We will try to find other available ways.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the AppRecordingManager API, however, it limits the recording to the resolution of the screen. Maybe the best solution is to capture the coordinates of each rectangle in an array in real-time, and then add a MediaOverlay at that location to the MediaComposition before preview.

Comment: I agree with you. And we are also trying to do the solution to process every video frame with a rectangle just as you described.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a video effect to get the detected face rectangle added as part of the video capture. What this will allow for is access to the raw bitmap data in each media sample where you can then draw whatever you need.

[FaceDetector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facedetector?view=winrt-19041) may be better than [FaceTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facetracker?view=winrt-19041), but you will lose the predictive nature of the later. You could try to refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/detect-and-track-faces-in-an-image) which may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, creating a video effect with FaceDetector and adding it to the video stream makes a lot of sense. I did the workaround mentioned in a previous comment which was to capture the coordinate data produced by FaceTracker, and then create overlays with those coordinates. It looks good but the video effect method is better. Thanks!